# Usage of 'use' or 'using' in programming languages

Tags: php, namespaces

I always thought the main goal of a namespace is to prevent name collision and ambiguity.

#1 problem fixed by namespaces from php.net:

> Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP
>   classes/functions/constants or third-party
>   classes/functions/constants.

However, most languages implement the "use" keyword in some way to alias or import other namespace to the current one. I know how it works, but I don't understand why such functionality is ever used.

Isn't using a 'use' keyword effectively defeating the purpose of a namespace?

```
namespace core\utils;

class User {
    public static function hello(){
        return "Hello from core!";
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------

namespace core2\utils;

class User {
    public static function hello(){
        return "Hello from core2!";
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------

namespace core2;

//causes name collision, we now have two different classes of type 'utils\User'
use core\utils; //without this line the result is 'Hello from core2'

class Main {
    public static function main(){
        echo utils\User::hello();
    }
}

Main::main();
//outputs Hello from core!
?>
```

Am i missing something or is usage of 'use' keywords really generally discouraged?

Either way, under what circumstances is it actually a good idea to sacrifice the encapsulation?

I used to use use, but now I am not sure when use should be used.

**Edit:** Alright let me get this straight: If I use 'use' to get short name, how is that better than just declaring the class in global namespace? See below:

```
namespace core\utils\longname {    
    class User {} //declare our class in some namespace
}

//------------------Other File---------------------------
namespace { //in another file import our long name ns and use the class
    use core\utils\longname\User as User;
    new User();
}
```

^ What is the advantage of namespacing like that against this declaration:

```
namespace {    
    class User {} //declare our class in global namespace
}

//------------------Other File---------------------------
namespace { //in another file just use the class
    new User();
}
```

Is there any difference at all between the two?

Comment: "Using" is used because it's both a pain in the arse and contrary to good visual understanding to have to spell out everything all the time.

Comment: That is indeed true, but it feels like I am hurting the namespace. Where is the border between ambiguity and readability?

Comment: Aliases ought to be redundant. But are currently a by-product of namespaces not being used for their intended purpose, but rather to create identifier taxonomies.

Comment: Programming is always a matter of trade-offs.  Hard-and-fast ruled don't exist, no mater how much the "experts" may try to convince you otherwise.  The art in programming is knowing where to draw the faint gray line.

Answer (score 3):

+1 Very Interesting question

My Opinion

The keyword `use` as so many uses and functionality imagine this

```
use core\utils\sms\gateway\clickatell\http\SmsSender  as SmsCSender 
use core\utils\sms\gateway\fastSMS\ftp\Smssender as SmsFSender
```

Now Compare

```
if(!SmsCSender::send($sms))
{
    SmsFSender::send($sms);
}
```

To

```
if(!core\utils\sms\gateway\clickatell\http\SmsSender::send($sms))
{
    core\utils\sms\gateway\fastSMS\ftp\SmsSender::send($sms);
}
```

Conclusion

Without `namespace` and `use` i would not be able to achieve such a clean readable code so what i think is that `namespace and use complement each other`  rather than 'use'  defeating the purpose of a namespace

Comment: Yes, the `use...as` paradigm is much better than the schemes with only `use/using/import/et al`.  Unfortunately it's not available in all languages, and when it is there are sometimes oddball restrictions (or at least archaic "conventions" that render it less than ideal).

Comment: Of course this is probably the reason most people use 'use'. However, is it not pretty much the same as just declaring the class in global namespace then? That way you don't have to mess with 'use', _and_ you have clean code. What advantages do you continue to get over global ns when in the end you just merge the namespaces anyway with 'use'?

Comment: without global `ns` that instance would not be possible .. global `ns` is what define the path that `use` is acting upon